# Placeholder for unknown number of digits

Tags: input-fields, input, placeholder

I would like to add placeholder on a HTML input type which could hold number between 1 and n (unknown large number of digits, for practical reasons it will be limited to some number, let say 10).
This input type is a part of a "input group" (three fields which combined hold an information) which contains another two input types, first one having fixed size of two allowed digits and second one of three allowed digits. I was thinking to use hash ('#') sign as a placeholder for first two fields, however, I am not certain how to deal with third input.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="##" /> 
<input type="text" placeholder="###" />
<input type="text" placeholder="?????" />
```

Comment: When the user enters data, do they need to enter the exact number of digits or could they enter fewer digits - following from your examples, could they enter one digit in the first field and one digit in the second or must they enter two digits in the the first and three in the second?

Comment: @AndrewMartin They have to enter exactly two digits in the first field and three digits in the latter one.

Answer (score 2):

The Nielsen Norman group has an [interesting read](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/) on placeholder text. The important take-away is that **regardless of what you put in as placeholder text, you should clearly label each field.** In most cases, the labels should be [placed on top of the fields](https://uxplanet.org/10-rules-for-efficient-form-design-e13dc1fb0e03) for easy scanning. Additionally:

> If some of the fields require an extra description that is essential
>   to completing the form correctly, it’s best to place that text outside
>   the field so that it is always visible.

**Convention suggests that placeholder text should describe what goes in the box.** For example, may credit card forms use this convention:

[image]
(image from http://www.freewebmentor.com)

If your input field has a well-understood name, you could put that name in the placeholder box. The exact nature of the number wasn't listed in the question, so I can't make a concrete suggestion without clarification.